# Filter unique objects from any array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have an array of objects in javascript, I am creating a new array from it but only with some properties. What I need is to filter the unique objects and eliminate the repeated ones, I'm trying to do it in the same function but I don't know if it's possible

This is the array:

```
let filters = [
  {
     "model":"audi",
     "year":2012,
     "country":"spain"
  },
  {
    "model":"bmw",
    "year":2013,
    "country":"italy"
  },
  {
    "model":"audi",
    "year":2020,
    "country":"spain"
  }
]
```

This is the function:

```
function filterObject(data: any) {
  let result = data.map((item: any) => {
    return {
      hub: {
        country: item.country,
        model: item.model
      }
    }
  })
  return result

}
```

This is what I get:

```
[
   {
      "hub":{
         "country":"spain",
         "model":"audi"
      }
   },
   {
      "hub":{
         "country":"italy",
         "model":"bmw"
      }
   },
   {
      "hub":{
         "country":"spain",
         "model":"audi"
      }
   }
]
```

This is what I need:

```
[
   {
      "hub":{
         "country":"spain",
         "model":"audi"
      }
   },
   {
      "hub":{
         "country":"italy",
         "model":"bmw"
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: @pilchard I've been reviewing those answers, but I can't find anything easy to adapt, what I need is something more generic to be able to take advantage of it in any array of objects, but I'm still trying with some example of that question

Comment: The accepted answer is extremely easy to adapt by simply passing an array of keys to construct the composite key from. Otherwise see [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) and the duplicate it's closed for for generic options you can pass to `filter()`

Comment: example of a generic `unique` based on the duplicate: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q6t1f7bj/) (you could update the answer to use a `Set` instead of null object)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` to ensure only unique items:

```
function filterObject(data:any) {
  const uniqueObjects:any = [];
  const uniqueMap = new Map();

  data.forEach((item:any) => {
    const key = item.model + item.country;
    if (!uniqueMap.has(key)) {
      uniqueMap.set(key, true);
      uniqueObjects.push({
        hub: {
          country: item.country,
          model: item.model
        }
      });
    }
  });

  return uniqueObjects;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=42&ssc=2&pln=24&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAZglsYgE4GcIF4IG0BQEIG9c88AiAWwHsATEYEgLhIEMBXKmEgGiOJIE8QTRAwBMABgCMI7sVIBjCiwB2YRHwYlkAByYwlJIgF8ZBHhHLVaGgEZkA7lzP9Bw+uIkBmE-MUq1GmDAmYHUjb1NZCxo6RlsHcOchUUkvJwVlVXVGQODQvGMiQkjKaI1WdkdIgSS3MXEE9L8szR09A3zsAF1sbChlOTAYCiVoOAREAHlrACsQAYAKKiYg+iYlPgBKCIgFJWRIZRgARxYQKdmB5FX19CxOgG4iXf2IQ5OQAFkmLVulEDsIF8tPMNo8iEsggA6KAURAAUSYcgAFvN5oEQGRrpt0AA+bZ4Z6QADWID4t3RZEhJVoEAA1BAKZDGplHrIYFAIPMAIRvU5AyFIpjIeYkzZbIqyV5KY5876Q5DgEWkzgQVSnUFmPC8s4zOZgZCQrQsZAoiWSiBIljWej4807XyZG2M5lqcLm6nAJ0ISkezXEQx+wwa2QB-IaoiIcAsRAjbXnPXIR4B7CE0bwJAgKgYWDpya6hY58bIDXPCigSHACgAc3mhYzVA2QA)